# How to pick a chunk from the text column in postgresql

Tags: postgresql-9.6

I have a table ABC with the following 2 columns

```
id(PK)        Name

1             Verapamil 160mg tablets (X Y Z Pharmaceuticals Ltd) 56 tablet 4 x 14 tablets
2             Zocor 10mg tablets (You & Me Ltd) 28 tablet 2 x 14 tablets
3             Atenolol 100mg tablets (NoName Pharmaceuticals Ltd) 20 tablet 2 x 10 tablets
```

I would like to select 56 tablet from id=1, 28 tablet from id=2 and 20 tablet from id=3. Is there anyway in Postgres to select just the chunk from the text?

Comment: Are these texts encloses always between `**`?

Comment: no, I would like bold these figures, ** is not required, removed **

Comment: Is there a regular pattern? Like: `xxx tablet`

Comment: Yes, its a regular pattern

Answer (score 1):

```
create table abc (id int primary key, name text);
insert into abc values 
(1, 'Verapamil 160mg tablets (X Y Z Pharmaceuticals Ltd) **56 tablet** 4 x 14 tablets'),
(2, 'Zocor 10mg tablets (You & Me Ltd) **28 tablet** 2 x 14 tablets'),
(3, 'Atenolol 100mg tablets (NoName Pharmaceuticals Ltd) **20 tablet** 2 x 10 tablets');
```

If there is a pattern, for example: (1 or more digits) plus the word `tablet`, you can use a regular expression like this:

```
select 
    substring(name, '([0-9]+ tablet)')
from
    abc;
```

> ```
> | substring |
> | :-------- |
> | 56 tablet |
> | 28 tablet |
> | 20 tablet |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=4a09106eff28e4a3acbe34d7645b5784)*

Comment: Thanks, worked for me